# Object length is 0, but there are several items within it

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an object (dataObj) that returns several items within it, inside a $getJSON:

```
var cities = ['london', 'paris', 'munich', 'geneva', 'prague', 'vienna', 'barcelona', 'istanbul'],
    totalCities = cities.length,
    i = 0,
    $container = $('#cities'),
    htmlFragment,
    data,
    obj,
    dataObj = {
        cities:[]
    };

function appendData() {

    var city = cities[i],
        locationQuery = escape("select item from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places where text='" + city + "') and u='c'"),
        locationUrl = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + locationQuery + "&format=json&callback=?";

    if ( i === cities.length ) { return };

    $.getJSON( locationUrl, function( data ) {
        var condition = data.query.results.channel[0].item.condition.text,
            temperature = data.query.results.channel[0].item.condition.temp;

        obj = {
            city: city,
            condition: condition,
            temperature: temperature
        };

            dataObj.cities.push(obj);

        // $container.append(html);

        appendData();

    });

    i = i + 1;
}

appendData();

var source   = $("#some-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var dataObjExample = { cities: [
        {city: "london", condition: "Cloudy", temperature: "8" },
        {city: "paris", condition: "sunny", temperature: "5" },
        {city: "munich", condition: "Rainy", temperature: "3" }
    ]};

console.log(dataObj);
console.log('dataObj:' + dataObj.cities.length);

console.log(dataObjExample);
console.log('dataObjExample:' + dataObjExample.cities.length);

$("#content-placeholder").html(template( dataObj ));
```

When I console.log the dataObj.cities it all looks fine and there are lots of items, however the length is at 0, which I'm sure is the source of my problems. I've been fiddling around and searching for some time for a solution, with no avail. Any ideas clever people?

**update**

Apologies, in my delirious state last night I meant to write: dataObj.cities.

I've added 2 console.logs to the JS. One is the real data and shows the length of dataObj.cities.length as 0. The other is where the object is created manually and displays dataObjExample.cities.length correctly as 3.

Please view the console at this url: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36374911/weather%20app/index.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you looking at the length?

Comment: The length is being checked **before the asynchronous `getJSON` call returns.** That's why it's zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'appendData' function is a recursive function which doesn't work in the same way as a for loop would.

When i === cities.length invoke another function which will have access your your completed array.

$(document).ready( function () {

```
var cities = ['london', 'paris', 'munich', 'geneva', 'prague', 'vienna', 'barcelona', 'istanbul'],
    totalCities = cities.length,
    i = 0,
    $container = $('#cities'),
    htmlFragment,
    data,
    obj,
    dataObj = {
        cities:[]
    };

function appendData() {

    var city = cities[i],
        locationQuery = escape("select item from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places where text='" + city + "') and u='c'"),
        locationUrl = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + locationQuery + "&format=json&callback=?";

    if ( i === cities.length ) { 
        buildTemplate();
        return;
    };

    $.getJSON( locationUrl, function( data ) {
        var condition = data.query.results.channel[0].item.condition.text,
            temperature = data.query.results.channel[0].item.condition.temp;

        obj = {
            city: city,
            condition: condition,
            temperature: temperature
        };

        dataObj.cities.push(obj);

        appendData();
    });

    i = i + 1;
}

function buildTemplate() {
    var source   = $("#some-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

    var dataObjExample = { cities: [
            {city: "london", condition: "Cloudy", temperature: "8" },
            {city: "paris", condition: "sunny", temperature: "5" },
            {city: "munich", condition: "Rainy", temperature: "3" }
        ]};

    console.log(dataObj);
    console.log('dataObj:' + dataObj.cities.length);

    console.log(dataObjExample);
    console.log('dataObjExample:' + dataObjExample.cities.length);

    $("#content-placeholder").html(template( dataObj ));
}

appendData();
```

});

Answer (score 4):

Plain objects like your "dataObj" don't have a `.length` property (unless you make/maintain one).  That's an array thing, and it only works with numerically-indexed properties.

Now, `dataObj.cities.length` will give you the length of that array.

Comment: dataObj.cities.length still gives the length at 0. Please see my updated url

Comment: @DanV the call to `.getJSON` returns immediately, and the callback code you pass in is called only when the HTTP request is complete. Therefore, when you check the length of the array right after you call your "appendData" function, the length is still zero because the response has not yet arrived. You have to put all that code *inside* the callback function.

Comment: I see the issue now. Its strange how the console.log shows all the items in the array still, yet the length is 0.

Comment: If you put a `console.log()` call inside your callback function, you'll note that it happens *after* the call outside the "appendData" function. (I always put unique markers in `console.log()` calls, like "dataObj A" and "dataObj B", so I can tell them apart.)

Answer (score 1):

You must target cities and query its length:

```
dataObj.cities.length
```

Also notice that Object prototype does not have a dynamic `length` property like Array prototype.